# How to remove following unique key issue

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, syntax-error, antd

Here I am using the ANT table component of react js. When I click on the link and goto related page where I'm using ANT Table component then "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."  This error reproduces each time.  Check my following code. What I am miss to add here? Please see my code and let me know.

```
     <Table dataSource={state.cardsList}>
        <Column
          title="Credit card number"
          dataIndex="cardNumber"
          key="cardNumber"
        />
        <Column
          title="Expiry month"
          dataIndex="expMonth"
          key="expMonth"
        />
        <Column title="Expiry year" dataIndex="expYear" key="expYear" />
        <Column
          title="Action"
          key="action"
          dataIndex="action"
          render={(text, record) => (
            <Space size="middle">
              {/* <a>Invite {record.lastName}</a> */}
              <a onClick={() => removeCard(record)}>Delete</a>
            </Space>
          )}
        />
      </Table>
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: why you create column instead of using `columns={columns}` attribute ?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html could help shine some light on this for you. Can you share what your data shape looks like? I.E. does *it* have a key property defined on each object. Is it unique within the dataset?

Comment: You can use rowKey prop on Table tag and assign unique key of your objects to it. for example <Table rowKey="id" ... />

Comment: In your case for all the records you will have the same key as "cardNumber"  for the first column. Similarly for other two columns as well. Key needs to be unique.

Comment: Thanks, guys for your valuable comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you do not have unique `key` properties in your `dataSource`.

Make sure that each element in your `state.cardsList` has a `key` property like this:

```
const dataSource = [
  {
    key: '1',    // unique key property
    name: 'Mike',
    age: 32,
    address: '10 Downing Street',
  },
  {
    key: '2',   // unique key property
    name: 'John',
    age: 42,
    address: '10 Downing Street',
  },
  ...
];
```

If your `state.cardsList` do not have unique keys then just map it and add the key:

```
<Table dataSource={state.cardsList.map((el, idx) => ({key: idx, ...el}))}>
...
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Often your existing data already has something unique that can be used as a `key` (it doesn't have to be named `key`).

Just set the `rowKey` when you create the `<Table>`:

```
<Table dataSource={state.cardsList} rowKey="id">
```